# Will replacing a 16.6nH inductor with 2 inductors in series total 16.6nH cause issues on RF board at 433MHz?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, inductor

I have a circuit based on SYN480R.
It has an inductor 16.6nH(L1). It works well however it is hard to find 16.6nH inductors. I can find other values that I can put in series and sum 16.6nH. Will it cause issues like decreased range etc?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: _"it is hard to find 16.6nH inductors."_ - what is the closest value you can find?

Comment: I was told that even 16.5nH or 16.7nH would not be too ok since they are all not so accurate so putting not the exact value wont work well.

Comment: The difference between 16.6 and 16.5 is 0.4%. Most inductors in that range have 2% or 5% tolerance. The datasheet says the coil and capacitor provide 'some' filtering, and considering that the (unspecified) antenna is connected directly to the top I bet the Q isn't very high. You could probably use a 17nH inductor with no noticeable effect.

Comment: thanks for your input! will definitely try it

Answer (score 6):

It should not be a problem if the parts are small and reasonably close together. 433MHz is a relatively low frequency.

The inductance of the traces is important whether there is one inductor or two, only a few mm can have an effect greater than the tolerance of the inductor.

Comment: you mean the traces that connect the components on the receiver need to be "thin" like 6mm lets say?

Comment: More short than thin.

Comment: copy that, will try to design them on the same pad so distance will be almost 0.

Answer (score 3):

Your L1 is a tuned circuit along with C3.  If you change the value of L1 you will need to also change the value of C3 to maintain the same frequency.

In THEORY a combination of more than one inductor will have the same effect as a single inductor but in practice it may introduce additional parasitics that you will need to accommodate.

Often in circuits like this you will see an adjustable L or C so that the output circuit can be adjusted to achieve maximum output at the desired frequency.  It's not clear how critical your tuning is for this application.